# Convert String returning method to List<String> returning method in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want the following method to return List of type String instead of String return type, The other method from which following "build" being called will receive List of type String (not StringBuilder)

```
public String build(String Uri, String Id) {

        StringBuilder DocUri = new StringBuilder();
        if (Uri.contains("newString")) {
            DocUri.append("user-profile1/users/").append(Id).append("/user.xml");
            DocUri.append("user-profile2/users/").append(Id).append("/user.xml");
            DocUri.append("user-profile3/users/").append(Id).append("/user.xml");
        }
 
        return DocUri.toString();
    }
```

Output Should Be :
where '1' is the Id passed to the above method

```
[user-profile1/users/1/user.xml, user-profile2/users/1/user.xml, user-profile3/users/1/user-profile.xml]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out something like this,

```
public List<String> build(String Uri, String Id) {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    if (Uri.contains("newString")) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            values.add(String.format("user-profile%s/users/%s/user.xml",i,Id));
        }
     }
    return values;
}
```

If you want to append more `user-profile` you can increase the value in `for-loop`